# getting mysql max() value

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Structure

```
Name  qty
Milk  12
Bread 10
Pen   100
Pencl 100
```

My sql code to get the maximum qty

```
SELECT Name, MAX(qty) FROM item
```

But it is giving Milk 100 as the answer. how to get the correct answer?

Comment: Take out the name column.

Comment: MySQL really shouldn't allow the use of aggregate functions (eg: `MAX()`) without a `GROUP BY` clause. It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT Name FROM item
WHERE qty = (SELECT MAX(qty) FROM item)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT Name,qty FROM item ORDER BY qty DESC LIMIT 1
```

**[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c66e/1)**

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the products that have the maximum quantity in the table:

```
SELECT name, qty FROM item WHERE qty = (SELECT MAX(qty) from item);
```

Comment: I'm really sorry, my mistake. Answer editted with the correct query.